# Can Windows Authentication be used with WebLogic on a Linux OS?

Tags: sql-server, linux, windows-authentication, saml, weblogic-10.x

The application runs on Oracle WebLogic 10.3.6 and a Linux OS, using an MS SQL Server database. Currently it uses SQL authentication and SAML. It seems Windows Authentication is only possible when a Windows OS is used (local environment is Win7).

Is there a way to avoid changing the production server? To configure WebLogic to use Windows Authentication on a Linux operating system?

By using sqljdbc.jar and sqljdbc4.jar (I believe) and changing the configuration options under data sources enables Windows Authentication locally when the OS is Windows. In Linux, this does not work.

Comment: I'm not a DBA, nor am I a Linux expert, but I think the name **windows** authentication might suggest it's only possible on windows OS.

Comment: I will edit my question to add additional details; in this case, windows authentication refers to the end-users of the application - meaning capturing the user ID from their end when they attempt to access the application. The OS on which the application resides, I think, should not be a constraint. In this case, when an end-user navigates to the application URL, the application should capture their windows credential and check if they are authorized. As of now I am not clear on how the app server's OS has an impact on this process.